# ipython notebook - style of markdown cell

Tags: css, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[image]

Changing font color of header with custom.css file is simple:

```
.cm-header {color: #f8dda1 !important;}
```

but does anybody know how to change color of lists (ordered and unordered), html tags (green in the picture) and paths (red in the picture)?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you use the inspection tools in your browser to see what CSS classes apply to them?